# C#.net How to loop through objects within objects

Tags: object, nested

Could someone help me. In C#.net I need to pull the properties and their values from objects within objects. Object "pc" may have other objects of different types in it and I need to recursively move through "pc" extracting what I need.

Picture of hierarchy found here:
http://www.virtualizeplanet.com/pcobjects.jpg

I've tried pass the val property into a separate object "cc" the tried to iterate through it with this code but I don't get the right results:

```
object cc = pc.val;
foreach (var pp in cc.GetType().GetProperties())
{
string name = pp.Name;
}
```

Comment: What do you need to loop through these for and how do you know what you'll need?  Is this decision made at run-time or known beforehand?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Add some code to your post, it will be easier to understand your problem.

Comment: I need the name property and value and the val property and value. If the val property has multiple indexes I need to iterate through them and name property and value.

Comment: it looks like your example of what you tried is just going to overwrite the name variable you have inside your foreach loop.  Can you elaborate on what's "wrong" about the results you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Could you solution be along these lines?

```
string name = PC.Name;
int[] values;
foreach (obj value in val)
{
    values.Add(value);
}
// Do stuff
```

Comment: Hi Jake I'm probably inputting wrong but that error. val doesn't exist as an object that I can reference. Please see the code I added above. I successfully passed pc.val into a separate object "cc". I just need to iterate through that. Or

Comment: Also Jake there is no method to "add" to the array "values" in your code.

Comment: I might be on to something:

     object anArray = pc.val;
     IEnumerable enumerable = anArray as IEnumerable;
     if (enumerable != null)
     {
     foreach (object element in enumerable)
     {
     // etc...
     }
     }

Comment: @RickyEl-Qasem, I believe the Add method is part of the List implementation.  Can you try calling `.ToList()` on your array and then using the Add method?